# Selecting item from dynamic listbox in selenium JAVA

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to click on multiple privileges from "Available privilege" and move it to "Assigned privileges", however, the list changes after each scroll so, in one go I am not able to retrieve complete list items.

[image: ListBox]

Below is the html source for the same.

```
<div id="listBoxContentsource" style="-webkit-appearance: none; background: transparent; outline: none; border: none; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 541px; height: 198px;"><div style="outline: none 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 560px; position: relative; height: 404px;"><div role="option" id="listitem0source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Grants access to the Admin module on a global level, allowing users to access data which are related to all groups and individual users" id="jqxWidget1d58e406">ADM_ACC_GLOBAL</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem1source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 25px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Grants access to the Admin module on a group level, allowing users to access data which are related to the users from their own group" id="jqxWidgetf9e82031">ADM_ACC_GROUP</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem2source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 50px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Grants access to the Admin module on a user level, allowing users to access data which are related ONLY to their own account" id="jqxWidget7fd6d172">ADM_ACC_OWN</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem3source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 75px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Enable a User to edit Group's FieldTrax Virtual Number, FieldTrax Sender ID" id="jqxWidgetf6801832">ADM_OPT_GROUP_ADMIN_FT_SHOW</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem4source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 100px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="This setting allows users to set how many users can be maximally assigned to a group" id="jqxWidget5073c223">ADM_OPT_GROUP_ADMIN_SET_MAX_USERS_PER_GROUP_ENABLE</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem5source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 125px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Changing quota that is assigned to group, for applying and removing " id="jqxWidgetf2a5e5ad">ADM_OPT_MANAGE_QUOTA_GROUP</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem6source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 150px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Enable a User to assign and deassign all available privileges" id="jqxWidgetc2ebc33b">ADM_OPT_ROLES_IGNORE_PRIVILEGE_ASSIGNABILITY</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem7source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 175px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Allow User to add / edit a MobileTrax Access" id="jqxWidget47252eba">ADM_OPT_USER_ADMIN_ACCESS_MT</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem8source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 200px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Allow User to add / edit a Web Access">ADM_OPT_USER_ADMIN_ACCESS_WEB</span></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem9source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 225px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem10source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 250px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem11source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 275px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem12source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 300px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem13source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 325px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem14source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 350px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem15source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 375px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem16source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 400px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem17source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 425px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem18source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 450px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div><div role="option" id="listitem19source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 475px;"><span style="white-space: pre; visibility: hidden;" class=""></span></div></div></div>
<div role="option" id="listitem0source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Grants access to the Admin module on a global level, allowing users to access data which are related to all groups and individual users" id="jqxWidget1d58e406">ADM_ACC_GLOBAL</span></span></div>
<div role="option" id="listitem1source" class="jqx-listitem-element draggable jqx-draggable" style="height: 24px; top: 25px; left: 0px;"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 531px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-item jqx-rc-all"><span data-toggle="tooltip" data-content="Grants access to the Admin module on a group level, allowing users to access data which are related to the users from their own group" id="jqxWidgetf9e82031">ADM_ACC_GROUP</span></span></div>
```

Till now I have done the below:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("source"));
List<WebElement> values = ele.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'listitem')]"));
for (WebElement val : values) {
        System.out.println(val.getText().toString());// Prints the values of the Listbox
        if(val.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("ADM_ACC_OWN"))
        {
            val.click();
        }
```

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something simple like a CSS selector, `#listBoxContentsource [id^='listitem']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for all the responses. I have solved the issue.

Kindly refer below code:

```
public void selectPrivileges(String Privilege) {
    WebElement listbox = driver.findElement(By.id("source"));
    Set<String> roles = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    int clickedEventsCount = 0;
    List<WebElement> elements = listbox.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'listitem')]"));
    try {
        String[] privileges = Privilege.split("\\|");
        while (true) {

            Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<>();
            for (WebElement element : elements) {

                String role = element.getText();
                if (null != role && !role.isEmpty() && role.length() > 0) {
                    for (String privilege : privileges) {
                        if (role.equalsIgnoreCase(privilege)) {
                            // move
                            element.click();
                            driver.findElement(By.id("add")).click();
                            clickedEventsCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    rolesSet.add(role);
                }

            }

            if (clickedEventsCount == privileges.length) {
                break;
            }

            driver.findElement(By.id("jqxScrollAreaDownverticalScrollBarsource")).click();

            if (!roles.addAll(rolesSet)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the selenium Select ?

here is an simplified example of custom select method that uses selenium select :

```
public WebElement selectOption(final String option, WebElement element) {
        final Select select = new Select(element);
        select.selectByVisibleText(option);
        return element;
    }
```

Comment: There is no select tag hence, the above code can not be used.

Comment: The HTML is in the question... it's all DIVs and SPANs.

Comment: exactly, with a source code i can make an iteration that uses dynamic xpath selectors to identify elements that are similar or identical (as dom elements).